# How to have a custom message validity in Google recaptcha using JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, recaptcha

How to have a custom message validity in Google recaptcha?

If the user didn't or forgot to checked the Google Recaptcha checkbox before clicked the submit button. There's a popup message will displayed, the the user need to check first the checkbox.

I have JS that will validate the input text box and it is working. But I don't know how to implement it in Google Recaptcha

JS:

```
function InvalidMsg(textbox){
     if(textbox.validity.patternMismatch){
        textbox.setCustomValidity('Please enter your name here');
    } else if(textbox.validity.valueMissing){
         textbox.setCustomValidity('This field is required');
    } else {
                textbox.setCustomValidity('');
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the reCaptcha verify response call back. Something like this: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=reCaptchaCallback&render=explicit'>

You will also want to attach your error message to the reCaptcha container you are using.

```js
var RC2KEY = 'sitekey',
    doSubmit = false;

function reCaptchaVerify(response) {
    if (response === document.querySelector('.g-recaptcha-response').value) {
        doSubmit = true;
    }
}

function reCaptchaExpired () {
    /* do something when it expires */
}

function reCaptchaCallback () {
    grecaptcha.render('id', {
        'sitekey': RC2KEY,
        'callback': reCaptchaVerify,
        'expired-callback': reCaptchaExpired
    });
}

document.forms['form-name'].addEventListener('submit',function(e){
    if (doSubmit) {
        /* submit form or do something else */
    }
    else {
        /**
         * Show your error message here.
         * InvalidMsg function may not work.
         * recaptcha does not have properties you are checking for.
         */
    }
})
```

Comment: The code is only a sample. You have to use your own form name.

Comment: the error message will be a popup in the checkbox? if it's unchecked?

Comment: You will need to add your `InvalidMsg` functionality inside the else statement described above.

Comment: it's not working in my side. `document.forms['myform'].addEventListener('submit',function(e){
       if(textbox.validity.patternMismatch){
        textbox.setCustomValidity('Please enter .....');
    } else if(textbox.validity.valueMissing){
         textbox.setCustomValidity('This field is required');
    } else {
       textbox.setCustomValidity('');
    }
    return true;
})`

Comment: I pasted this in the console and it works. So I'm not sure.
`var textbox = {
    validity: {
        patternMismatch: false
    },
    setCustomValidity: function(customValidity) {
        console.log('customValidity > ', customValidity);
        return customValidity;
    }
}`

`document.forms['myform'].addEventListener('submit',function(e){ if(textbox.validity.patternMismatch){ textbox.setCustomValidity('Please enter .....'); } else if(textbox.validity.valueMissing){ textbox.setCustomValidity('This field is required'); } else { textbox.setCustomValidity(''); } return true; })`